# Incompatible type for argument and conflicting types

Tags: c, prototype, conflict, incompatibility

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy_arr(double, double, int);
void copy_ptr(double, double *, int);

int main()
{

    double source[5]={1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5}; 
    double target1[5]={0.0};
    double target2[5]={0.0};
    copy_arr(source, target1, 5);
    copy_ptr(source, target2, 5);
    return 0;
}

void copy_arr(double source[5],double target1[5],int arraysize)
{
    int count=0;
    puts("....copying using array notation.....");
    for(count=0;count<arraysize;count++)
        {
            target1[count]=source[count];
            printf("target 1 is : %d\t", target1[count]);
        }
}

double copy_ptr(double source[5],double *target2,int arraysize)
{
    int count=0;
    puts("....copying using pointer notation.....");
    for(count=0;count<arraysize;count++)
        {
            *(target2+count)=source[count];
            printf("target 2 is : %f\t", *target2);
        }
}
```

Errors::

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘copy_arr’ copy_arr(source, target1, 5);

error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘copy_arr’ copy_arr(source, target1, 5);

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘copy_ptr’ copy_ptr(source, target2, 5);

error: conflicting types for ‘copy_arr’ void copy_arr(double source[5],double target1[5],int arraysize)

error: conflicting types for ‘copy_ptr’ void copy_ptr(double source[5],double *target2,int arraysize)

I checked in internet but everything was mostly about prototypes. Mine are here but still I am getting this error! What is the reason?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i suppose the question is : can you help me solve the errors? :)

Comment: _...mostly about prototypes._ Check the prototypes. `double` is not the same type as `double[5]`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @John C Now only I know they are not same haha!

Comment: I didn't mean that offensively, just thought that a light push would get you reoriented. You can almost always just copy the signature line of a function for its prototype, since names are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have following prototypes:

```
void copy_arr(double, double, int);
void copy_ptr(double, double *, int);
```

then you declare those as:

```
void copy_arr(double source[5],double target1[5],int arraysize)
```

and

```
double copy_ptr(double source[5],double *target2,int arraysize)
```

there's a problem. your prototypes take single doubles as arguments, not arrays of doubles. then, in prototype copy_ptr returns nothing, but in declaration returns double.
change those to:

```
void copy_arr(double[], double[], int);
void copy_ptr(double[], double *, int);
...
void copy_arr(double source[],double target1[],int arraysize)
void copy_ptr(double source[],double *target2,int arraysize)
```